# Error Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' building APK

Tags: android, react-native, apk, android-install-apk

After trying to build APK once and fixing an error, I got an error executing `./gradlew assembleRelease` again: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' building APK

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The problem occured becaused when I tried to build once, it has created drawables dirs on `android/app/src/main/res/`. Then when I tried on second time, it has shown me this error `Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' building APK`

I just deleted the drawable-* dirs and it worked.

Hope it helps!

[image]

```
rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
```

[image]

Comment: Won't this delete all your app icons and any assets you have in there?

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach No! It won't delete app icons. App icons are stored in the same folder with the folder name mipmap.

Comment: Now it's giving 

`A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade' 

Error because images inside drawable are missing

Comment: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.myApp.myapp:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

Comment: Now I get this error.. A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction

Answer (score 28):

As addition to accepted answer, if there is a "raw" folder in the same directory, also you must delete that.

Comment: This is a good point to take into account. I only solved erasing this folder too.

Answer (score 13):

I just deleted the **drawable-*** dirs as well **raw dir** from

android/app/src/main/res/ and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly problem occurred when I tried to build once, it has created drawable dirs.
I was facing following issue:

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'E:\project\ionic\uvparentlan0.4\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Solution: I delete all drawable directories named "drawable-port-*****"

Now Build again  " ionic cordova build --release android "

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 11s
42 actionable tasks: 40 executed, 2 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it's a result of a duplicate file. Reading the error log, it seemed that I had a duplicate file name (two files with the same name). The issue resolved by removing one of the files (from a previous build if I remember it right).

Answer (score -1):

I changed .png to .jpg in drawable and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same error. Just clean your project and make a fresh build.
Works for me with sdk 33.

Sometime invalidate caches and restart helps as well.

Answer (score -2):

If you are facing this error from

```
\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\splash.png
```

change it to `jpg` extension

```
\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\splash.jpg
```