# React Native android build FAILD :app:mergeReleaseResources

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The App is working fine, in fact I have built 2 release APKs. This time I modified the code and came to do `./gradlew assembleRelease` and I got the following error:

### Error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

### Expectation

To generate a healthy APK ready to publish.

### Extra Info

1. I have done the signing and the .keystore in the right place `../android/app`
2. Updated `../android/gradle.properties` as instructed

Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.Close stacktrace
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:79)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
```

## Screenshot from the Scan1

[image: Screenshot from the Scan1]

## Screenshot from the Scan2

[image: Screenshot from the Scan2]

## Screenshot from the Scan3

[image: Screenshot from the Scan3]

## from android Studio - I believe it is related to the issue

[image: from android Studio - I believe it is related to the issue]

## Screenshot from the Scan4

[image: Screenshot from the Scan4]

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of your errors. Copy your error, edit your question and paste them in.

Comment: @Mohammed Al Joohi, try clearing your build folder and stop any debuggers/emulators attached and then try the build.

Comment: Please include the whole stacktrace from the '[Screenshot from the Scan3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5bPa.png)' image. Have you tried: `/gradlew clean assembleRelease`?

Comment: I did that multiple times

Comment: @AndreasLorenzen I have posted it in the post. Thank you for putting your time into this with the post edits, much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it may not be able to create the output directory? Check what is going on here: `OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51`. Can you clean the target location manually?

Comment: I did clean the previous release APK if that’s what you mean Sir.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' building APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652381/error-execution-failed-for-task-appmergereleaseresources-building-apk)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this could be a duplicate of this question:

[Error Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' building APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652381/error-execution-failed-for-task-appmergereleaseresources-building-apk)

> The problem occured becaused when I tried to build once, it has
>   created drawables dirs on android/app/src/main/res/. Then when I tried
>   on second time, it has shown me this error Execution failed for task
>   ':app:mergeReleaseResources' building APK
>
> I just deleted the drawable-* dirs and it worked.

To remove the directory `drawable--*`:

```sh
rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
```

Comment: there is no drawable folder inside res

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There is no drawable folder inside res, still the error occurs.
While running the emulator the build is successful and emulator works fine but I couldn't take release apk because of build failure.