# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'. react native realse build

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have tried multiple solutions online can't get the build to work

I get a Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

  > [raw/app] C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\Marist-Mobile-App\android\app\src\main\res\raw\app.json    [raw/app] C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\Marist-Mobile-App\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\raw\app.json: Error: Duplicate resources
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 24s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\Marist-Mobile-App\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\Marist-Mobile-App\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\Marist-Mobile-App\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\Marist-Mobile-App\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

I don't know what to do

With --info

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
```

:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 2 mins 2.218 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
  >   IDLE
- Try::bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 35s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date

Can someone please help me...

Comment: could you show the error info when you use --info build

Comment: I have updated the --info build

Comment: try to use ./gradew build --info to build the android project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native android build FAILD :app:mergeReleaseResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057989/react-native-android-build-faild-appmergereleaseresources)

Answer (score 1):

in path **android/app/src/main/res/** delete all directory  with start name **drawable_***