# React native build process fails

Tags: react-native

I am building my app for the first time.
I had to delete everything in my `app/src/main/res/` folder because I ran into another issue. Is this related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652381/error-execution-failed-for-task-appmergereleaseresources-building-apk)?

I also may have deleted this file by accident when trying to fix the build.

Why is this error happening and how do I fix it?

[Edit]
I did some searching and it seems I deleted the mipmap folder. What is this folder and how can I replace it?

```
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.

> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
 /Users/charbel/Desktop/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-25:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.awesomeproject:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
     
 /Users/charbel/Desktop/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-25:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.awesomeproject:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
     
 /Users/charbel/Desktop/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-25:19: AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.awesomeproject:style/AppTheme) not found.
     

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 19s
```

Answer (score 1):

Check node modules, its look like all modules is not installed properly.
you should run -  npm install / npm update to install all related node modules.

Also you can run with --info and --debug to check the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I accidentally deleted the icon folders I made a new project then moved them where they belong
`react-native init newproject`

`cp -R android/app/src/main/res/* ../project/android/app/src/main/res/`