# React Native Error Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' building APK

Tags: react-native, apk

I have read and follow this solution to delete drawable files but it is still not working.
This is the link that I follow: [Error Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' building APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652381/error-execution-failed-for-task-appmergereleaseresources-building-apk)

Here is the error code after i have followed the above method:

```
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [raw/app] C:\Users\User\Documents\Me\codes\Startup Project\iOrder_Merchant_recreate\android\app\src\main\res\raw\app.json     [raw/app] C:\Users\User\Documents\Me\codes\Startup Project\iOrder_Merchant_recreate\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\raw\app.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons] C:\Users\User\Documents\Me\codes\Startup Project\iOrder_Merchant_recreate\android\app\src\main\res\raw\node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons.json       [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons] C:\Users\User\Documents\Me\codes\Startup Project\iOrder_Merchant_recreate\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\raw\node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons.json: Error: Duplicate resources

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5m 10s
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you please close all your nodes and kill all the ongoing processes that are used in your current project and after that re-run your project. It works for me everytime, tell me after trying this

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i have found an answer and have posted it at the answer section.

Answer (score 3):

After researching on google and find no other similar solution, i then try to delete the duplicate files mention in the error and it works!
These are the 2 files i have removed:

1. android\app\src\main\res\raw\app.json
2. android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\raw\app.json

After removing these 2 files, i then run:

```
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Then it shows me build successful :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean the duplicates resources.

use the following commands

```
rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/raw
```