# How to build flutter apk after upgrade

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, build, apk

After I upgraded my project, I can't build it again, anytime I want to build it, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\***\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3639cf706c0e2c46b95a8210e85b1d33\transformed\material-1.8.0-alpha01\res\values\values.xml: Resource and asset merger: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface</macro>'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> C:\Users\***\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3639cf706c0e2c46b95a8210e85b1d33\transformed\material-1.8.0-alpha01\res\values\values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface</macro>'

BUILD FAILED in 48s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           51.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' building APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652381/error-execution-failed-for-task-appmergereleaseresources-building-apk)

Comment: I have the same problem; try upgrading the packages to the newest version as well as kotlin. I'm not sure if this can help but try.

Comment: @eamirho3ein No

Comment: @AbdElRahmanAymen done already no fix