Flutter Android build apk :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource
Build APK Error Android
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseJavaResource'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
com.google.common.base.VerifyException (no error message)

android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21' // หรือเวอร์ชันที่สอดคล้องกัน
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2' // อัปเดตเวอร์ชันของ Android Gradle Plugin
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

android/app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace = "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapp"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-android'
    // เพิ่ม dependencies อื่น ๆ ที่ใช้ในโปรเจกต์ของคุณ
}


I think your problem was related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652381/error-execution-failed-for-task-appmergereleaseresources-building-apk
